# How to use printf to debug TCL source v8.4

Tags: tcl

I am using **TCL** as an embedded control in my system and I need to modify its core source a bit, I mean the code under generic/, such as `tclInterp.c`. I am adding printf to the source code to trace my modification, but for some reason I cannot see the output. I see the code is using `fprintf`, I used that and tried both stdout and stderr, still not working.

I already added "`--enable-symbols=all`" to run configure and re-build the packages. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: What is the functionality that you're trying to add and which you need debugging of Tcl itself to figure out? (I hope it isn't having an interpreter in multiple threads; that _really_ won't work…)

Answer (score 3):

You should use a debugger instead. Adding printf statements to the core code will result in your output appearing on stdout which your Tcl scripts may redirect. using `fprintf(stderr, ...)` might be less likely to clash with the scripts you run. `--enable-symbols` just results in a debuggable build - it will not affect the ability to write to stdout but will result in a debugger being able to produce meaningful output.

You don't say - but if you are on Windows and are embedded in a graphical program then you probably don't have stdout anyway. On Windows, you will be best to use OutputDebugString and watch the messages in Visual Studio's output window or sysinternals DbgView.
On unix, the console you launch the application should show the output. However, actually tracing your mods with a debugger will be the best route.

Are you sure you really need to modify the core? Seems unlikely to me. Normally you just add additional commands to the interpreter to provide the interface to your hosting application. The Tcl API offers access to pretty much everything you might reasonably want to fiddle with.

Comment: Also, you could try dumping the log messages to a file (time-stamped, of course). That's how I debug servers (especially where the server is running as multiple processes).